# stylesheet links in controller

Tags: angularjs

my source data contains URLs pointing to css files and I need to load these files when my template is rendered.

a controller has something like this:

```
$scope.links = myData.query();
```

and in the view I tried this:

```
<link ng-repeat="link in links" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{link}}">
```

of course, before angular gets to filling in the `{{link}}` part, the browser complains about the URL `{{link}}` that it does not exist.

so I ended up with just emitting markup instead of the links:

```
$scope.links = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://example.com\">";
```

and in the template:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="links"></div>
```

I cannot even use `ng-bind-html` I have to use the unsafe version.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Remove the for keyword from your ng-repeat: `<link ng-repeat="for link in links".../>` should be `<link ng-repeat="link in links".../>`

Comment: yes, thanks. it was just a typo in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use [ngHref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref).

```
<link ng-repeat="link in links" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="{{link}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are always using AngularJS hash tags normally must have the appropiate directive module in this case **ngHref**. If you don't use this you will most likely return a 404 error until angular has time to replace the link with the appropiate URL.

Here refer to the Documentation for more information. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref